# Проблема с рекурсивной lambda

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

Пишу функцию по поиску директорий в поддиректории. Выбор пал на рекурсивную lambda функцию.

Код такой:

```
void dirListFind = [&dirListFind](const QString &directory, QStringList &dirList)
    {
        QDir dir(directory);

        dirList = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

        for (auto i = 0; i < dirList.size(); i++)
            dirList.push_front(dirListFind(dirList[i]);
    };
```

А вот ошибки:

[image: log]

Почему такое поведение? Вроде саму лямбду захватил, но, видимо, как-то не правильно.

И почему странно на void ругается?..

P.S. Методы поиска поддиректорий эффективнее с удовольствием выслушаю, но проблема в данном вопросе имено с лямбдой, прошу учесть.

Comment: Так а в честь чего это вы объявили переменную `dirListFind` с типом `void`???

Comment: @AnT ну потому что мне не надо, чтоб моя лямбда мне что-то возвращала... Почему это проблема? Разве я не могу сделать void lambda?

Comment: Как это не надо? А что вы командой push_front в dirList добавляете? Результат dirListFind, т.е. пустоту

Comment: @Михаил Краев: Почитайте что-нибудь по синтакситсу. Этот `void` не имеет никакого отношения к тому, что возвращает сама ваша лямбда. В этом месте пишется тип самого лямбда-объекта. Этот тип - неизвестен, поэтому там всегда будет `auto`, а не `void`. Тип возврата лямбды будет писаться через `->` после `)`.

Comment: @Александр не усмотрел, косяк, спасибо

Comment: @AnT и Вам спасибо, прочитаю. как то я упустил этот момент...